# ftp_connect error (download file from FTP)

Tags: php

I'm trying to download file via php script, but unfortunately with this script i get error:

> PHP Warning:  ftp_connect(): php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo
>   failed: nodename nor servname provided, or not known in
>   /Users/apple/projects/asystem/download_dump.php on line 15

i try to put different FTP address test it and it worked fine

so the problem is 100% in the server address...

```
// define some variables
$folder_path = "/Users/apple/projects/asystem";
$local_file = "auct_lots_full.xml.zip";
$server_file = "auct_lots_full.xml.zip";

//-- Connection Settings
$ftp_server = "ftp://xxxx_user:Eecohshxxxxxx@auctionsdata.xxxxx.com"; // Address of FTP server.
$ftp_user_name = "xxxxx_user"; // Username
$ftp_user_pass = "xxxx"; // Password
#$destination_file = "FILEPATH";

// set up basic connection
$conn_id = ftp_connect($ftp_server);

// login with username and password
$login_result = ftp_login($conn_id, $ftp_user_name, $ftp_user_pass);

// try to download $server_file and save to $local_file
if (ftp_get($conn_id, $local_file, $server_file, FTP_BINARY)) {
    echo "Successfully written to $local_file\n";
} else {
    echo "There was a problem\n";
}

// close the connection
ftp_close($conn_id);
?>
```

Comment: Did you ping given domain from host?

Comment: Are you running this in Windows Machine?

Comment: if i use this link it works

Comment: im using MAC OS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

so yes! the problem was that i use wrong path to the FTP. This code works:

```
//-- Connection Settings
$ftp_server = "auctionsdata.xxxxx.com"; // Address of FTP server.
$ftp_user_name = "xxxxx_user"; // Username
$ftp_user_pass = "xxxx"; // Password
```